# Is there any reasonable way to short-sell Bitcoin

Tags: currencies

It is not an official currency (yet?) but definitely has a market, and as such, I might be intrested in short-selling some. Are there any reliable, way to bet against it?

Comment: The set of offerings changes over time, but will appear here: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade#Financial

Answer (score 1):

Even though I would strongly **advise against it** doing a search turns up:

- https://icbit.se/
- http://mpex.co/

---

There are probably others but do take into consideration that the majority of these "exchanges" have statements like the one listed bellow (taken from https://btct.co/faq):

> **Is it legal for this exchange to operate?**   (...)
>
> 1. No assets on the site are to be considered real.
> 2. The use of this site is for **educational and entertainment purposes only**.
> 3. If an asset issuer on this site defaults, you have ZERO RECOURSE. (not like you have any recourse in most international BTC situations
>      anyway.)